# How can I access the clipboard without a window?

Tags: kotlin, clipboard, compose-desktop

I'm working on a Compose application which manipulates the clipboard.

So I have been using this:

```kotlin
val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
```

This worked fine, until I hoisted it out of the `Window` scope.

i.e., this is OK:

```kotlin
if (showMainWindow) {
    Window() {
        val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
    }
}
```

While this is not OK:

```kotlin
val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
if (showMainWindow) {
    Window() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Conceptually, the clipboard exists outside all windows, so it should be accessible even if there are no windows currently shown. And I certainly don't want my window to be lurking around when it isn't needed.

Where do I go from here?

- Is there a way to inject `ClipboardManager` somehow to make it accessible inside `application` scope instead of window scope?
- Should I even be using `ClipboardManager`? It is a pretty bad API. Plenty of people copy/paste images and the API only supports text. Compare that with what AWT gets. (which is still limited)
- Should I abandon even AWT and find a way to access the native clipboard API? :(